# What is the quickest way in Python to identify lists with common elements A & B in indices [i] & [j] without using expensive for loops?

Tags: python, list, filter, nested-lists

**Context:**
I went through many similar questions on the internet for list filters and tried all suggested solutions. But they all seem to be fine for comparing two different lists. But they do not give desired results for a my list-of-lists.

**Problem:**
I have a list of lists and two different numbers that I want to check if they are located in the first two index elements (index[0] and index[1]) of the nested lists within the list of lists. I wish to identify all such lists and then if such lists exist, compare the fourth index member of all those similar lists against a fixed number.

**My Sample list:**

```
[[1, 4, 65, 77, 22.0], [3, 2, 12, 55, 77.0], [1, 4, 16, 99, 13.0]]
```

**Numbers to check:**

```
`index[0] == 1 and index[1] == 4.`
```

The above list of lists has two such nested lists where the first index member is 1 and second index member is 4.

Hence we we now compare the fourth index member of each similar list against our reference weight = 17.

Thus there is one list where the number 22 is greater than our reference number 17; and another list where the number 13 is lesser than our reference number 17.

**My Output should be :**

```
return True if there is at least one list where the fourth index is < reference weight

return False if all values in fourth index are > = reference weight
```

What I am looking for is an efficient way of quickly identifying the similar lists within the list of lists. ***I know for loop is an option, but performance becomes an issue since my list-of-lists can get very big over time (during every iteration new list members get added to the list of lists).***

Comment: I don't understand what you want to get as output. Do you want a list-of-lists `lists_where_4th_value_is_smaller = [[1, 4, 16, 99, 13.0]]` and another list-of-lists `lists_where_4th_value_is_greater = [[1, 4, 65, 77, 22.0]]`?

Comment: Hi, I updated my question with output information

Comment: So the result should be `True` if at least one list has a smaller value, but it should also be `True` if no list has a smaller value? So the result should be `True`, always?

Comment: I made a typo in Output. The result should be false when all values are > = weight and True if < weight

Comment: Why the unaccept on jpp's answer? Doesn't it do what you want?

Comment: Actually, my list of lists keeps growing throughout the time I run my code. The classification process has to be repeated every time the list populates new nested lists. So it increases the big-O complexity over time. I am trying to find out if there can be any quick filtering process based on column values so that my performance will not drop irrespective of the current dimension of the list.

Comment: So in short, it's too slow? If you have performance requirements, you should say so in your question. (I know you asked for "efficient way", but if the performance is a big issue then you need to be more explicit about it.)

Comment: I tried to explain that in this terminal sentence of my question "I know for loop is an option, but performance becomes an issue since my list-of-lists can get very big over time." When I said over-time, I meant that the list of lists grows dynamically over time.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.defaultdict` to group lists similar by your definition with O(n) complexity. You should test to see whether the performance of this solution suits your needs.

```
from collections import defaultdict

lst = [[1, 4, 65, 77, 22.0], [3, 2, 12, 55, 77.0], [1, 4, 16, 99, 13.0]]

d = defaultdict(list)

for item in lst:
    d[tuple(item[:2])].append(item)

# defaultdict(list,
#             {(1, 4): [[1, 4, 65, 77, 22.0], [1, 4, 16, 99, 13.0]],
#              (3, 2): [[3, 2, 12, 55, 77.0]]})
```

---

For the second part of your question, you can iterate your dictionary items:

```
res = {k: any(i[4]<17 for i in v) for k, v in d.items()}

# {(1, 4): True, (3, 2): False}
```